# Accessing array with Hooks and useState

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I have the code below:

```
const [personsState, setPersonsState] = useState({
  person: [
    { name: 'Max', age: 28 },
    { name: 'Manu', age: 29 },
    { name: 'Stephanie', age: 26 }
  ],
  showPersons: false
});
```

Is it best practice to access the person array by using the code below?

```
persons = (
  <div>
    {personsState.person.map((person) => {
      return <Person name={person.name} age={person.age} />;
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Hooks, React recommends that you *separate out* different types of state into different variables. Unlike class components, you shouldn't try to put all state into a single variable.

From [their FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables):

> We recommend to split state into multiple state variables based on which values tend to change together.

Consider having `persons` (the array) and `showPersons` (the boolean) instead:

```
const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    { name: 'Max', age: 28 },
    { name: 'Manu', age: 29 },
    { name: 'Stephanie', age: 26 }
  ]);
const [showPersons, setShowPersons] = useState(false);
```

And then generate JSX by mapping over the `persons` variable, instead of `personsState.prson`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me, only one extra suggestion which is related to [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) section of React documentation:

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

In order to eliminate warning, you need to add `key` to each iterated elements in `.map()` as:

```
<div>
    {personsState.person.map((person, index) => {
      return <Person key={index} name={person.name} age={person.age} />;
    })}
</div>
```